# Encoding Problems On Linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, encoding

I have a file on Oracle Linux Server 5.9 where its charset is utf-8, but when I want to print it with cat, less, tail, nano etc. I can't see some characters. When I copy file to Windows 7, I'm able see all characters without any problem on notepad.

Do you know how can I correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're connecting over SSH, set your terminal encoding to `UTF-8`. I know PuTTY defaults to the system encoding (`cp1252`) or did at one point, but you can change that under Options -> Window -> Translation. Look at the documentation for your client if you have a different SSH client or terminal that you're using.